# Chilli Plant Leave Tips

Tags: chili

[image]

My chilli plant is growing however the tips of the leaves are drying, any suggestions ? Is this normal ?

Comment: Do you rotate the plant? The window seems to have very different temperature. Maybe tips just touch sometime windows and are "burned" by cold. Personally I would put away for windows: in winter they can live without much direct sun.

Answer (score 1):

They are pretty hardy plants as long as they don't get too cold.  So I would not worry about them with just that little bit of damage on the tip.